# Are the PW1100G and PW1400G engine series not certified by the FAA?

Tags: faa, aircraft-certification

I was digging around the FAA type certificate data sheet (TCDS) database and I could not find the entries for the PW1100G and PW1400G engines series. I then went to the EASA TCDS database and both of them were categorised under the PW1100G-JM title. Have these two engine series not been certified by the FAA? Was it because they were for European aircraft OEMs (PW1100G for A320neo, PW1400G for Irkut MC-21)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are certified by the FAA. The following 1100/1400 models:

> PW1133G-JM, PW1133GA-JM, PW1130G-JM, PW1129G-JM, PW1127G-JM, PW1127GA-JM, PW1127G1-JM, PW1124G-JM, PW1124G1-JM, PW1122G-JM,PW1431G-JM, PW1431GA-JM, PW1431GH-JM, PW1428G-JM, PW1428GA-JM, PW1428GH-JM

Are certified under TCDS (type certificate data sheet) [E00087EN](https://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgMakeModel.nsf/0/74e4c2086661f360862584120046b423/$FILE/E00087EN_Rev6.pdf) (PDF).

Note: The certificate holder is International Aero Engines, LLC, and I was able to find it by searching https://rgl.faa.gov for "E00087EN", which I got from the [neo's TCDS](https://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgMakeModel.nsf/0/7aab29f325fff8d98625850a005ac672/$FILE/A28NM_Rev43.pdf).

Comment: Thanks! I was initially searching based on Type Holder and it wasn't listed under P&W. Interesting how IAE is the holder instead. I thought all the GTFs were solely developed by P&W.

Comment: @YongHauKit: You're very welcome. IAE is [~50% P&W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Aero_Engines#Shareholders). I don't know why they went that way.